# Java - derby - unsigned int

Tags: java, derby, unsigned

I would like that one of my columns in a specific table would not get negative numbers.
Is there a way to declare an unsigned int in derby DB ?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there a way to declare a column "unsigned int" in a Derby DB table?

A: I believe answer is "No":

- http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj124.html
- http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj124.html

... HOWEVER ...

You should easily be able to "CAST" the stored value in any query:

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Java (unfortunately) has no support for unsigned arithmetics.

But you can still use Java's `int` and make your own methods to do unsigned arithmetic, like [this](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned_arithmetic.shtml). Even better is to create an `UnsignedInteger` class and let it handle all that arithmetic.

I don't know if it's worth it though. You can just use `long` as jtahlborn suggests.

Comment: And equivalently, even a 32-bit value (e.g. 0xffffffff) can be 'cast' to the corresponding unsigned int in your query

Comment: Guava has a helper class already written for you: [UnsignedInts](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html).

Comment: @Onca - I don't know why they're babbling about "Java Unsigned" and "Guava".  The question you asked is "How can I store this in Derby DB"?  SUGGESTION #1: "Just store it as a signed 32-bit int" (in which case Guava UnsignedInts might be applicable - but I believe DerbyDB "cast()" is probably better!).  SUGGESTION #2: Store it as a "long" (as jtalkborn suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Java does NOT support the type `unsigned int`, as opposed to C or C++.

On the other hand, there is a simple way to circumvent this limitation by using:

- An intermediate `long` variable/literal
- A cast to `(int)`

First, let us note that both signed and unsigned int have the same number of bits; they are both 32 bits in size.

The main difference is, that for signed integers the MSB (Most Significant Bit) or bit 0 is used to indicate that the actual integer is negative or positive.

If this bit is set to 1 the integer is negative, if it is set to 0, the integer is negative. So, you will end up with 31 bits for the value of the integer, and 1 bit for the sign.

For unsigned integers, all the 32 bits are used to represent the value of the integer. You can now have larger numbers.

The `signed integers` range from `-2^31` to `(2^31 - 1)`

The `unsigned integers` range from `0` to `(2^32 - 1)`

To show the size limitation issue, try to compile the following snippet:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
        int i = 2_147_483_648;//This line will generate a compiler error
    }
}
```

The compiler will complain saying `integer number too large`.

Let us see how we can circumvent this and still store this number in a Java integer, and retrieve it back.

The idea behind the proposed solution stems from the fact that a series of bits is interpreted to mean something. It could be a representation of an image, a Java object, a C struct, a character, etc.

You "interpret" the series of bits based on what you "expect" that series of bits to represent. If you are expecting a character, you might be looking to match the series against an ASCII table. If you are expecting an image, you might be looking to decode a JPEG.

Now, and coming back to integers, if you are looking for `signed integers` you will interpret the MSB as the sign bit. If you are looking for `unsigned integers` you will interpret the MSB as part of the value.

To give an example, let us assume that you have the following series of 32 bits:

- in hex 0x8000_0000 or in binary 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000

The MSB is set to 1 all other bits are 0.

If you are looking for/expecting a `signed integer` these 32 bits would be interpreted as the representation of the negative decimal number `-2_147_483_648`

If you are looking for/expecting an `unsigned integer` these same 32 bits would be interpreted as the representation of the positive decimal number `2_147_483_648`

Hence, the solution would be to store the values in a signed 32-bit integer and interpret them as an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Here is how we will modify the previous snippet and save `2_147_483_648` into an integer value and be able to print it correctly.

To do so, we will:

- First, use a `long` intermediate datatype/value
- Then cast that value to `int` to save it
- Finally, mask/ignore `&` the extra bits and display it

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //1. cast a 64-bit long value that fits into a 32-bit int
        int i = (int)2_147_483_648L;
        //2. Mask the extra long bits
        System.out.println(i & 0x0000_0000_FFFF_FFFFL);
    }
}
```

The `long` variable can hold 64 bits, and its MSB, or sign bit, is not affected by its first 32 bits. You will notice a  bitwise operation happening here:

```
i & 0x0000_0000_FFFF_FFFFL
```

This is telling the compiler to ignore, or mask, all the bits that are beyond the first 32 bits we are interested in. Our integer is 32-bit.

If you want to do some arithmetic operation on the `int` value before saving it, you could resort again to a `long` intermediate variable.

Here is how, and this will be the proposed solution:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int i = (int)2_147_483_648L;
        int j = 1_000_000;
        long tempL = i + j;//Use a temp long to perform the operations
        i = (int)tempL; //We save back into i and store in a DB for example
  
        //Now we use the saved value to display it, for example
        System.out.println(i & 0x0000_0000_FFFF_FFFFL);
    }
}
```

Good luck and hope the above helps!